# How long can olives be left out of the refrigerator?

Tags: food-safety

I left a bottle of garlic stuffed olives out overnight. Are these still safe to eat?

Answer (score 6):

Traditional pickles made with brine and vinegar are very hardy, and where used in the days before refrigeration to store food over many months

The secret is to only use a very clean utensil to remove a single daily portion from the main storage vessel, and otherwise keep the main storage vessel tightly closed and in a cool and dark location

With modern pickles, who knows? Read the side of the jar, if it seems to have a decent amount of salt and/or vinegar it should be just fine

If you haven't put dirty utensils or your hands in it, it will last a long time (weeks or months, depending on the ambient temperature level)

Otherwise, just keep them in the fridge :-)

Comment: Since these olives are garlic-stuffed, a cited source might be more helpful.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez Why? What's special about garlic stuffed?

Comment: Garlic can grow botulism but upon my own further reading, is more succeptable in a low-oxygen, low acidic environment such as olive oil.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez Pickled olives have a pH around 4, (though some taste close to zero :-( ). Botulism is not common in all of the world, and can be in any food that has been near the ground

Comment: @TFD-because I'm curious by nature, I dug a little more and found this very informative article on botulism.  Though I'd bet the OP's olives are OK, I feel better informed now! :-) http://www.fsis.usda.gov/FACTSheets/Clostridium_botulinum/index.asp